# PDO insert query slowing the site down

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, pdo, innodb

On my site I have coded a function that shows you how many unique visitors and how many pageviews I get per day.

The problem is that sometimes the insert query takes forever and in InnoDB theres no `DELAYED INSERT` function.

***Edit:***  It is using InnoDB, what I mean with long loading time is around 6 seconds instead of like 0.1-0.5 seconds. As soon as I remove the logging the site is much faster.

The `$b` array bellow contains browser info, but according to XHProf its the PDO query that's taking so long to execute.

The insert code is this:

```
$values = array(
        'time' => time(),
        'ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
        'page' => rtrim((isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : 'index'), '/'),
        'browser' => $b[11][0] . ' ' . $b[11][1],
        'os' => $uos,
        'referred' => (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && !preg_match('|^' . Config::getValue('site', 'url') . '|', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : ''),
    );

    $this->table->insert($values);
```

and the insert function code:

```
public function insert($table, $data) {
    ksort($data);

    $fieldNames = implode('`, `', array_keys($data));
    $fieldValues = ':' . implode(', :', array_keys($data));

    $sth = $this->prepare('INSERT INTO ' . $table . '(`' . $fieldNames . '`) VALUES (' . $fieldValues . ');');

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $sth->bindValue(':' . $key, $value);
    }

    $sth->execute();
}
```

Comment: This question needs more details. What insert query? How long is "forever"? What does the database schema look like?

Comment: Please post table definition. If primary key is not autoincrement and table is large, the random I/O involved in the insert may be the reason for slowing

Comment: I thought you wanted to do a `DELAYED INSERT`, but you don't. So I'd say it takes longer because you don't do the `DELAYED INSERT`, right?

Comment: You can't have DELAYED INSERT when using INNODB.

Comment: is that your actual code? `$this->table->insert($values);` you never give `$data` but you specify your actual values as the `$table` parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minor optimization. The way you are doing your binding you can get rid of the foreach statement and pass the array directly to execute. PDO will map the arrays key to the :binding names you created in the prepare statement.

```
$sth->execute($data);
```

That said, you should look at your slow query log in mysql to see what is going on. Even though you are using Innodb, there are scenarios where Innodb will lock the table. That could be why inserts are taking a long time sometimes. You can reduce your slow query threshold to something like 3 seconds to capture the queries. The log will tell you how much time was spent in each stage (i.e. locked).

Answer (score 1):

"On my site I have coded a function that shows you how many unique visitors and how many pageviews I get per day."

Are you executing a live query for every page request? That might well be a performance problem of its own. It won't kill anyone if you'd query those figures every hour or so, and cache the value. Subsequent page views can then use the cached value instead of a live one.

"The problem is that sometimes the insert query takes forever and in InnoDB there's no DELAYED INSERT function."

It could be that its not the INSERT itself that's slowing you down, but that your MySQL instance is simply busy all the time calculating page views. There's a chance this problem will go away once you start serving cached page view figures.

Comment: Especially when using keys on one or more fields (excluding primary).

Answer (score 0):

As deceze said, it may need more details. But I guess it might get stuck in "Config::getValue('site', 'url')". Btw, is your mysql a remote one?

Answer (score -3):

Is there a reason you're using `prepare` instead of just calling `pdo -> exec()`?

Searching around shows many people bench marking `prepare` as being much slower and more intensive than the using `exec()` especially when you aren't expecting any values back (also see the doc for [Prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) - it notes being designed to optimize calling the same query multiple times).

Instead of binding your values you could do something like this -

```
function insert($table, $data) {
    ksort($data);

    $fieldNames = implode("`, `", array_keys($data));
    $fieldValues = implode("', '", array_values($data));

    $this->exec("INSERT INTO $table (`{$fieldNames}`) VALUES ('{$fieldValues}')");
}
```

Comment: This is a great way to introduce an SQL injection vector.